# How to knit/Sweave to a different file name?

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

By default, the knit/Sweave command will generate a tex file with the same name as the .Rnw file. I want to give it and the subsequent pdf file a different name is it possible?

Comment: You have an `output` argument in `knit` or `knit2pdf`.

Comment: Crap! I don't know how I missed that. Is there a way to append a variable name from the knitting file (in a R code chunk) to the filename? I ask because I am already generating an ID in the knit, I don't want to generate another random number for the file name.

Comment: The answer is yes definitely, but depends on how you generate the id in .Rnw. You will get answer if you show a sample.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out.

Comment: Where can I set this argument? Background: I'm compiling rnw files with RStudio by clicking on the "Compile PDF" button. What I want is that each time I create a pdf file, the current date get appended to the pdf filename and thus formely generated pdfs do not get overwritten.

Comment: @moabit21 Instead of clicking "Compile PDF" use the function knit2pdf from knitr. In that you can pass an argument output, so say my Rnw file is called "test.Rnw" I would call knit2pdf(test.Rnw,output=paste0("test",Sys.time()))

Answer (score 3):

In the header of an `.Rmd` file, you can specify a file name:

```
---
title: "My title"
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [ 
      "--output=Custom_name.pdf" 
    ]
---
```

For `.Rnw` files you can directly call the function `knitr::knit2pdf`:

```
knit2pdf(input.Rnw, output="Custom_name.pdf")
```

Comment: +1 for `pandoc_args`, but this is only valid for RMD files. As the question is about RNW, you maybe want to add the suggestion from the comments (`knit2pdf`, argument `output`) to your answer.